# Customize cancel button of searchbar in titanium

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, searchbar

I'm working on a titanium project. In which I need a customized searchbar like below.

[image: Design doc]

But when I created the searchbar it looks like;

[image: Output]

I want to change the image of cancel button. I searched a lot for customizing the searchbar in titanium, but couldn't find any solutions.

I'm creating searchbar in the following way:

```
var searchLocation = Ti.UI.createSearchBar({ 
    showCancel:true,
    height:55,
    top:45,
    width:'102%',
    backgroundImage:"../../Images/bg_search.png",
    borderRadius:'5'
});
```

---

Then I tried something different.

1. I created a view, a searchbar without cancel button and a customized button.
2. Added the searchbar to that view
3. Added the button to right of that searchbar.

   ```
   //holder view
   var searchHolder = Ti.UI.createView({
      height   : 55,
      width    : '100%',
      top      : 45,
      backgroundImage:"../../Images/bg_header@2x.png",
      layout   : 'horizontal'
   });

   //search bar
   var serLocation = Ti.UI.createSearchBar({
      height:55,
      top:0,
      width:'85%',
      backgroundImage:"../../Images/bg_header@2x.png"
   });

   //Calendar button
   var calButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
      height   : 45,
      width    : 45,
      backgroundImage:"../../Images/nav_calendar.png"
   });

   searchHolder.add(serLocation);
   searchHolder.add(calButton );
   ```

It's working perfectly.

But I'm searching for any alternative solutions. Is there any built-in-methods to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't bult-in-methods for this. Your working solution is the best one.

Comment: @Dawson Toth i have added a searchbar in which there appears a autofocus bottom line in it how could i remove it.Please help me

Comment: @allDroid I'm really not sure what you mean... you should create a new SO question with screenshots and code reproducing your problem to see if the community can help you!

Comment: @Dawson Toth  Please check this posted question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34264016/no-color-property-for-searchbar-in-titanium.I need some suggestion and help.